# django - annotate() - Sum() of a column with filter on another column

Tags: django, listview, django-annotate

I have the following two models.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_group=models.ForeignKey('productgroup.ProductGroup', null=False,blank=False)
    manufacturer=models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=False,blank=False)
    opening_stock=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product_group', 'manufacturer')
```

and

```
TRANSACTION_TYPE=(('I','Stock In'),('O','Stock Out'))
class Stock(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey('product.Product', blank=False,null=False)
    date=models.DateField(blank=False, null=False,)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    ttype=models.CharField(max_length=1,verbose_name="Transaction type",choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE, blank=False)
```

I need to list all products with `stock_in_sum=Sum(of all stock ins)` , `stock_out_sum=Sum(of all stock outs)`  and `blance_stock=opening_stock+stock_in_sum - stock_out_sum`

This is what I've achieved so far.

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    model=Product

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ProductList, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('product_group','product_group__category','manufacturer')
        queryset = queryset.annotate(stock_in_sum = Sum('stock__quantity'))
        queryset = queryset.annotate(stock_out_sum = Sum('stock__quantity'))
```

I need to get

1. `stock_in_sum` as the `sum(quantity) where ttype='I'`
2. `stock_out_sum` as the `sum(quantity) where ttype='O'`
3. `blance_stock` as `product.opening_stock + stock_in_sum - stock_out_sum`

along with each Product object.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregationhttp://)

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    stock_in_sum = Sum(Case(When(stock__ttype='I', then=F('stock__quantity')), output_field=DecimalField(), default=0)),
    stock_out_sum = Sum(Case(When(stock__ttype='O', then=F('stock__quantity')), output_field=DecimalField(), default=0)))
)
```

To make the sums, and after that compute the balance with [F() expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(balance_stock=F('opening_stock') + F('stock_in_sum') - F('stock_out_sum'))
```

You can also chain the different operation instead of multiple assignations:

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(...).annotate(...).annotate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! It asked me to use ExpressionWrapper(). Got the first two data as follows
`queryset = queryset.annotate(
  stock_in_sum = Sum(Case(When(stock__ttype='I', then= ExpressionWrapper(F('stock__quantity'),
                       output_field=DecimalField()))))
  )
  queryset = queryset.annotate(
  stock_out_sum = Sum(Case(When(stock__ttype='O', then= ExpressionWrapper(F('stock__quantity'), 
                    output_field=DecimalField()))))
  )
  `

Comment: But `queryset = queryset.annotate(
  balance_stock = ExpressionWrapper(F('opening_stock') + F('stock_in_sum') - F('stock_out_sum'), output_field=DecimalField())
  )`  gives None for all rows with either of `stock_in_sum` or `stock_out_sum` is None.

Comment: Looks like I need to return 0 instead of None somewhere, but don't know how.

Comment: I edited the answer to add default values so it will not try to add `None`, but 0.

Comment: Brilliant! That gives the exact result I wanted. No more duplicate queries :)

Comment: How do I get count of related rows in Stock, filtered by ttype=I/O, along with this annotate? stock_in_count = stock_in_count = Count(Case(When(stock__ttype='I', then=1), output_field=DecimalField(), default=0)),  ???