# Getting the aggregate sum of a field from the other model in Listview

Tags: django

I have the following two models:

## models.py

```
class Model_Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False, unique = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name

class Model_ItemTransaction(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Model_Item, to_field = "item_name")
    item_sold = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item
```

With this listview:

## views.py

```
class View_Item(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model_Item.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
                sum_ = Sum(When(model_itemtransaction__item_sold))
            )
        return queryset
```

And my goal is to get the total value of "item_sold" for each item, and display this value on Listview. How can I make this work?

I have been looking at the [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregationhttp://) and [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506898/django-annotate-sum-of-a-column-with-filter-on-another-column/45510598#45510598), but to no avail.

Comment: You never specify *what* to sum up, only *when* to sum up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use conditional aggregation, you just need the sum

```
 queryset = queryset.annotate(
    sum_ = Sum('model_itemtransaction__item_sold')
 )
```

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as the correct one

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay. Thought I did it yesterday.